# When I use axios with Nuxt.js for API communication, I get an error saying 502 (Bad Gateway)

Tags: proxy, amazon-dynamodb, nuxt.js

A new registration screen is implemented, the development language is Nuxt.js, and the database is AWS / DynamoDB.
I want to register a user name, email address, and password in DynamoDB using the post method of axios this time, but I get a 502 error.

The code is below.

↓nuxt.config.js

```
  axios: {
      proxy: true
    },
  proxy: {
    '/regist': {
      target: 'requestURL',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/regist': '/'
      }
    },
```

↓signup.vue

```
<!-User name / email address / password input screen->
    <div class="container">
      <validation-observer v-slot="{ invalid }">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div>
            <div class="user_name">
              <p>UserName：</p>
              <text-field-with-validation v-model="username" rules="required" fieldname="UserName" />
            </div>
            <div class="mailaddress">
              <p>Mailaddress：</p>
              <text-field-with-validation v-model="mailaddress" rules="email" fieldname="Mailaddress" />
            </div>
            <div class="password">
              <p>Password:</p>
              <text-field-with-validation v-model="password" rules="required" fieldname="Password" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="registration-button" :disabled="invalid" @click="signUp">Regist</button>
        </div>
      </validation-observer>
    </div>

<script>
import TextFieldWithValidation from "@/components/TextFieldWithValidation";

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      username: '',
      mailaddress: '',
      password: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    signUp(){
      this.$axios.post('/regist',
      {
        m_users: {
            user_name: this.username,
            mailaddress: this.mailaddress,
            password: this.password
        }
      }
      )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert('✖︎✖︎✖︎');
      })
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

In order to avoid CORS restrictions, proxy is installed in nuxt.config.js.
I'm in trouble because I don't know the cause.
I would be grateful if you could tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

A 502 error is most likely a [server-side error](https://www.howtogeek.com/356389/what-is-a-502-bad-gateway-error-and-how-can-i-fix-it/#:%7E:text=A%20502%20Bad%20Gateway%20Error%20means%20that%20the%20web%20server,describe%20that%20kind%20of%20error.). Are you able to make the same request to your API using an app like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)?

Comment: I have never used Postman.
The request seems to have been sent, but the contents seem to be empty.
Is it wrong to use axios for API communication?

Comment: When I tried it with Postman, this was displayed.

Comment: There's way too many variables to check. I would eliminate your usage of axios as a variable first by `POST`ing/`GET`ing to something like [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/), make sure you're getting the proper responses. If you are, then you are most likely encountering an error server-side or your request body.